# How to use HttpRequest.php to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, httprequest

I need to use the HttpRequest class found in this php documentation http://php.net/manual/fa/class.httprequest.php.

This is for a feature where I need to fetch a data from an API.

How can I integrate this in Laravel or is there a plugin/builtin function that is the same as the linked class?

Answer (score 0):

Edit /app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCSRFToken.php.
Add your route that the API is calling back to under

```
protected $except = []
```

Then, in the controller method that gets called, try

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $action = json_decode($json, true);
```

And you should now how have the data from the API in an array,